# jquery message instead of alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When doing a login, is there a message that pops up in the form itself
instead of alert popup message? Instead of popup screen, I want it to just show a message, login success, and disappear and then redirect.

```
alert("Login successful.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Natively there is not.

You're thinking of a modal. Check out a jquery UI modal dialog example at https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example of a custom messagebox. You can design it however you like

https://jsfiddle.net/mba25ma8/1/

html:

```
<div id="messageBox">Loggin successfull</div>
<input type="text" placeholder="Login name">
<button>Login</button>
```

css:

```
#messageBox {
display:none;
background-color: blue;
border: 1px solid #abc;
color: white;
position: fixed;
padding: 20px;
top:0;
left: 50%;
height: 50px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
   $("button")
   .on("click", function(){
       $("#messageBox")
       .slideDown("fast",function(){
          $(this).delay(2000).slideUp("fast");
       });

    // redirect to new page here

   });

});
```